# Template doesn't rerender after change in Backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a view which renders a template `entry`. When the a model gets added to the collection `movieSeats` it does the `@collection.on('add', @appendEntry, this)` part which adds the template `entry` to the `#entries` container.

```
class Movieseat.Views.Entry extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['movieseats/entry']
  className: 'movie-frame'

  initialize: -> 
    @collection.on('change', @render, this)
    @collection.on('add', @appendEntry, this)
    @collection.on('destroy', @render, this)
    return

  render: -> 
    $(@el).html(@template(entry: @collection))
    this

  events: ->
    "click div":"showCollection"

  showCollection: ->
    console.log @collection

  appendEntry: (entry) ->
    view = new Movieseat.Views.Entry(collection: entry)
    $('#entries').append(view.render().el)
```

On a different view I have a event that removes a model from the collection.

```
class Movieseat.Views.MovieseatsIndex extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['movieseats/index']

  render: -> 
    $(@el).html(@template())
    this

  events: -> 
    "click li":         "addEntry" 
    "click .remove":    "destroyEntry" 

  addEntry: (e) -> 
    movie_title = $(e.target).text()
    @collection.create title: movie_title

  destroyEntry: (e) -> 
    thisid = @$(e.currentTarget).closest('div').data('id')
    @collection.get(thisid).destroy()
```

This also works, the movie gets removed from the collection **but the problem is** that when I remove a model from the collection, the `@collection.on('destroy', @render, this)` from the `Entry` view doesn't do anything. I have to refresh the page to see the result of the remove event.

**update**

In both views I've added `console.log (@collection)` to a click event on a div element. When I click on a div I get this result,

```
Backbone.Model {cid: "c5", attributes: Object, collection: Movieseats, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object…}
Movieseats {length: 8, models: Array[8], _byId: Object, _events: Object, constructor: function…}`
```

The first result is from the `Entry` view and the seconde from the `Movieseat` view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Render template inside template using Backbone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575526/render-template-inside-template-using-backbone)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried listening to the `remove` event on your collection instead of `destroy`?
http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

Add a quick console.log to your render to check which events are causing the view to re-run that function. In my experience, I always use `reset`, `add`, `remove` and `sort` events on collections, and `change`, `destroy`, and so on on individual models. It just makes more sense -semantically if you will- to me. Collections are not destroyed, but items are removed. :)

Comment: I've replaced `destroy` with `remove` but it didn't do much. I think I might have found what's the problem. I've updated the question.