# Render template inside template using Backbone

Tags: jquery, templates, backbone.js, coffeescript

I've got two views. The first view renders the `entry` template containing data from that collection in a list element.

```
class Movieseat.Views.Entry extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['movieseats/entry']
  className: 'movie-frame'

  render: -> 
    $(@el).html(@template(entry: @collection))
    this
```

The second view rerenders the above said template inside a `#entries` div which is being rendered in this `#showentry` template.

```
class Movieseat.Views.Showentry extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['movieseats/showentry']
  className: 'showmovie'

  initialize: -> 
    @collection.on('destroy', @render, this)
    @collection.on('change', @render, this)
    @collection.on('add', @appendEntry, this)
    return

  render: -> 
    $(@el).html(@template(entry: @collection))
    this

  events: -> 
    "click .remove":    "destroyEntry"

  appendEntry: (entry) ->
    view = new Movieseat.Views.Entry(collection: entry)
    $('#entries').append(view.render().el)

  destroyEntry: (e) -> 
    thisid = @$(e.currentTarget).closest('div').data('id')
    @collection.get(thisid).destroy()
```

This is the template structure,

Entry template,

```
<div data-id="<%= @entry.get('id') %>">
    <p><%= @entry.get('title') %></p>
    <p><%= @entry.get('id') %></p>
    <p class="remove">Remove</p>
</div>
```

ShowEntry template

```
<div id="entries"></div>
```

When I load the page the models get rendered in the `entry` template from the first view.  Then the second view takes all the entries in the collection and appends them to the `#entries` div container.

When I do action like delete or change a collection the second view rerenders the `showentry` template. But when it does that it does not repopulate the `#entries` with the models from the collection. Resulting in a empty `#entries` div, where before it was filled with `.movie-frame` divs containing models.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It's something the `backbone-on-rails` gem adds and CoffeeScript.

Comment: @TJ: It is CoffeeScript.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma please tag that guy in question so that you'll find experts familiar with it ;)

Comment: @TJ Tag him where? In my question? In this comment ... ?

Comment: You're giving your entry view a whole collection? Or are you just saying `collection:` when you mean to say `model:`? Any chance of a minimal functional demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com?

Comment: The project is a bit big to get a working fiddle, but I've tried to show the code I'm using and explain what's going on. Maybe you can spot what's wrong from there > http://jsfiddle.net/e2Lbox8v/

Comment: @PeterBoomsma obviosly in the question. There is no option to add tags in a comments as far as I know...

Comment: @TJ I'm not following. You want me to tagg mu-is-too-short in my question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two views, same action but show different results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573880/two-views-same-action-but-show-different-results)

Comment: @PeterBoomsma nop, Initially your question was not even tagged with coffee script.. and you mentioned rails.. So I simply suggested tagging the technologies you're using in question.. that's all..